# WebGLRenderingContext.texImage2D does not implement interface ArrayBufferViewOrNull

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm working on a WebGL project and all my textures render fine. 
When i wanted to implement a cubemap i started getting this type error.
`Argument 9 of WebGLRenderingContext.texImage2D does not implement interface ArrayBufferViewOrNull.` in all browsers. 
A fragment of my code i use to load the textures is,

```
    var cubeMap = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, cubeMap);

    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {   
        var img = cubeMapArr[i];
        console.log(img);
        gl.texImage2D(
            gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 
            0, gl.RGB, 1024, 1024, 0, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,img);
    }
```

the `cubeMapArr` holds HTMLImageElements.
Any ideas or experiences about this issue?
Using `gl.texImage2D()` like for example this,

```
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D,0,gl.RGBA,gl.RGBA,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,normalMapTexture);
```

works with no issues. 
Again `normalMapTexture` holds a HTMLImageElement.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the edit genpfault this question should be tagged opengl-es.

Comment: no it should not be tagged opengl-es because the error as nothing to do with opengl-es. OpenGL ES has no concept of ArrayBufferViews or HTMLImageElements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WebGL there are 2 forms of `texImage2D`

```
gl.texImage2D(bindPoint, mipLevel, internalFormat, format, type, HTMLElement);
```

where `HTMLElement` is either `HTMLImageElement`, `HTMLVideoElement` or `HTMLCanvasElement`

and then there's

```
gl.texImage2D(bindPoint, mipLevel, internalFormat, width, height, border, 
              format, type, ArrayBufferViewOrNull);
```

Your code is passing an `HTMLImageElement` to the second form of the function which is why it's complaining it's not an `ArrayBufferViewOrNull`

In other words remove `1024, 1024, 0,`  from your call to `gl.texImage2D`

In WebGL2 the form you used exists but be aware WebGL2 just shipped in September 2021 on Safari 15.

Comment: I updated firefox and used webgl2 context, i think it is only available in firefox. The second version(with more arguments) of `gl.texImage2d` function works with a `HTMLImageElement` there. Thanks for the answer the first version with less arguments works in webgl1 context.

Comment: WebGL2 has shipped in both Firefox and Chrome